# Javascript rendering. How to write Javascript so it doesn't continue executing code before a function call has ended

Tags: javascript

Not sure if my question is subjective/objective but as a JavaScript newbie i'm encountering this problem quite a lot. So here I go.

I'm used to write C#, so my JavaScript structure looks like C#. And just that, that gives problems I think ;-)
Let's give a simple example where I met my problem again today:

```
MyLibrary.fn.InitAddEntityForm = function () {
    $('a#btnAddEntity').click(function () {
            //post data and receive object with guid and isPersisted boolean
            var persistedObject = MyLibrary.fn.CheckAndSendAddEntityForm("name", "avatarurl.png");
            console.log("test");

            //check if persisted and go to next step
            if (persistedObject.isPersisted) {
                MyLibrary.fn.InitAddAnotherEntityForm(persistedObject.gdEntityId);
            } else {
                alert("Oops, something went wrong. Please call 911");
            }
    });
};


//////*****/////
//SOME FUNCTION THAT SENDS MY FORM AND RETURNS AN OBJECT WITH TRUE VALUE AND POSTED ENTITY ID
/////*****//////
MyLibrary.fn.CheckAndSendAddForm = function (txtName, ImageUrl) {
var postUrl = "/admin/add";
var persistedObject = new Object();
$.post(
    postUrl,
    { Name: txtName, ImageUrl: txtImageUrl},
    function (data) {
        if (data.Status == 200) {
            console.log("Post status:" + data.Message);
            persistedObject.isPersisted = true;
            persistedObject.gdEntityId = data.Data;
        } else if (data.Status == 500) {
            console.log("Failed to post entitiy");
        } else {
            console.log("Fault with Javascript");
        }
    }, "json"
);
return persistedObject;
```

};

Okay, thats it. Everything looks okay right? Browser says no.
I tried to debug it using firebug, looping over my code line by line, and that way the browser does what I want: Execute a new function to show the next panel in my wizard.

After placing a lot of Console.logs() in my code I figured out that this must be something about timing in JavaScript. In C# the code executes line by line, but apparently JavaScript doesn't. 
By placing that Console.log("test") I noticed that "test" appeared in my console before "Post status: Success!".

So here's my question, how should I write my JavaScript code so I have control over the way the browser executes my code?
Should I really replace the code below to the end of my CheckAndSendAddEntityForm()?

```
//check if persisted and go to next step
        if (persistedObject.isPersisted) {
            MyLibrary.fn.InitAddAnotherEntityForm(persistedObject.gdEntityId);
        } else {
            alert("fout");
        }
```

Is this how I have to write JavaScript: One big domino effect or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: The AJAX call is an asynchronous one, and the post status text is in the callback. So that bit _will_ run only after the browser receives a response from the POST. The function call on the other hand has ended and the rest of the code will run immediately.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: It do is a new world. Thx for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.post is a shortcut for an AJAX call, AJAX is by definition asynchronous, which means it won't wait on a response before continuing processing. If you switch it to a regular AJAX() method, there is an async option you can set to false, which will make it behave as you are expecting.

Alternatively you can also define a function to execute on successful return of the AJAX request, in which you can call the next step in your process chain.

Comment: Thx for this clear answer. This actually makes sense: 'async' ofcourse. 
I'll set this as an answer in a few minutes when possible.
I appreciate the other answers/comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX call is asychronous; that means that the callback method exposes by `$.post` will be executed when the request completes, but your javascript will continue executing as soon as the invoke to `$.post` finishes. If you want to do something after the ajax call is done, you need to provide a callback method and do something else, ex:

```
MyLibrary.fn.CheckAndSendAddForm = function (txtName, ImageUrl, callback) {
var postUrl = "/admin/add";
var persistedObject = new Object();

$.post(
    postUrl,
    { Name: txtName, ImageUrl: txtImageUrl},
    function (data) {
        if (data.Status == 200) {
            console.log("Post status:" + data.Message);
            persistedObject.isPersisted = true;
            persistedObject.gdEntityId = data.Data;
        } else if (data.Status == 500) {
            console.log("Failed to post entitiy");
        } else {
            console.log("Fault with Javascript");
        }

        callback(); // This is where you return flow to your caller
    }, "json"
);
};
```

Then you invoke like so:

```
var persistedObject = MyLibrary.fn.CheckAndSendAddEntityForm("name", "avatarurl.png", function()
{
        console.log("test");

        //check if persisted and go to next step
        if (persistedObject.isPersisted) {
            MyLibrary.fn.InitAddAnotherEntityForm(persistedObject .gdPronoId);
        } else {
            alert("Oops, something went wrong. Please call 911");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded. If you have asynchronous functionality, a simple boolean [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) variable will help not to allow invocations of a function while some processes are running.

If you want to execute asynchronous tasks one by one (like a domino line), you will need to use callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're encountering is the "asynchronous" bit of AJAX.  If you want to physically (as in the line line by line in the Javascript file) you can use the `.success`,`.pipe` or `.done` jQuery methods to add a callback to process the data further.  Don't embed your callbacks if you can help it, or you *will* get a "domino effect" as  you call it.